# Textview dissapear after changing Visibility of ImageView

Tags: android, xml, layout

Im building a row layout for my ListView and have a problem by it.

Currently my layout looks like this :

[image]

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ROW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_albumart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_titel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_albumart"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_albumart"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_artist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_albumart"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_albumart"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_eq_animation" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_equalizer1_white_36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_albumart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0:00"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I want to change the visibility of the `imageView_albumart` to `android:visibility="gone"` I get this result :

[image]

Can you see where my format problem is ? I just want to hide the imgAlbumart so Title and Artist TextViews stand alone.

Comment: Try set visibility "invisible", if you want to hide the image but the text to remain on the same position.

Comment: no , my textviews should align to left when the albumart is not there. If I make it inivisible ,albumart is invisible but the textviews have same position. Thats not what I want

Comment: Title **textview** depends on ImageView positon see the properties of textview `layout_alignBottom` and `layout_toLeftOf` or Otherwise Use `LinearLayout` you will get as you expext.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the View to **View.INVISIBLE** instead of **View.GONE**

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this, You Can Design the UI With Combination of RelativeLayout and LinearLayout. Do search in Google about design pattern and Usage Of Layouts in Android. You Will get ideas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@null"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ROW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@null">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_titel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_artist"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_game"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="0:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is problem in your layout 
change your layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ROW"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_titel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:text="Titel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_artist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:text="Artist"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titel"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_eq_animation" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_eq_animation"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/txt_artist"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_albumart" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_length"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0:00"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

it will do..